# Delete redundant MOSS content database entry

Tags: database, sharepoint-2007

In a sharepoint content database we have noticed there are a couple of records in the all_docs table that reference documents that no longer exist. The listid guid that they are associated with is not in the site so we have no way to view them and delete them. I think this was a result of moving a content database from another environment into this one.

Can anyone suggest the best approach to clean this up? I need to delete it as it is referencing a page layout that I cannot delete until this page has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Fear and loathing](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2009/07/06/the-undocumented-deleteconfigurationobject-parameter.aspx), it describes an undocumented stsadm command to delete an object by its id.

Comment: Can this be any object or is this specific to timer jobs? It says it cannot find the object when I pass in the GUID from the ID column in the database

Comment: It is not specific to timer jobs, as a colleague used it to delete an invalid AAM mapping, but the full extent of its usage is unfortunately unknown, sorry.